# Averageifs for multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Why am I getting #DIV/0! using the fuction in the picture? I am trying to get the average of (B2:B11) where A2:A11 equals hostcareers and A2:A11 equals hosttalent.

***Hostname function:***
[image]

Comment: The 2 conditions are mutually exclusive, so you're presenting nothing (null) to the average function (within the AVERAGEIFS). And you always get a #DIV/0 when you try and average nothing.

Comment: @Spinner So how should I approach it?

Comment: @Spinner I thought about this =AVERAGEIF(A2:A11,"hostcareers",B2:B11)+AVERAGEIF(A2:A11,"hosttalent",B2:B11), but I won't probably return the correct value.

Comment: Could use: =SUM(SUMIF($A$1:$A$11,"hostcarers",$B$1:$B$11),SUMIF($A$1:$A$11,"hosttalent",$B$1:$B$11))/SUM(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$11,"hostcarers"),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$11,"hosttalent"))

Comment: Or could use: {=(SUM(IF($A$1:$A$11="hostcarers",B1:B11))+SUM(IF($A$1:$A$11="hosttalent",B1:B11)))/(SUM(IF($A$1:$A$11="hostcarers",1))+SUM(IF($A$1:$A$11="hosttalent",1)))} Note the {}, This is an array function.

Comment: @Spinner I got 13.75  after tryinng this but the input should be 3.25. =SUM(IF($A$1:$A$11="hostcareers",B1:B11))+SUM(IF($A$1:$A$11="hosttalent",B1:B11))/(SUM(IF($A$1:$A$11="hostcareers",1))+SUM(IF($A$1:$A$11="hostcareers",1)))

Comment: @Spinner the second function is accurate.

Comment: Yeah, sorry... I corrected that already. See above. Both the SUMIF and Array SUM(If... solutions offered work (and do the same thing). Pick the one you're most comfortable with. :)

Comment: You can also use an array constant to reduce some of the verbosity.  For the non-array function: `=SUM(SUMIFS(B1:B11, A1:A11, {"hostcareers", "hosttalent"})) / SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A11, {"hostcareers", "hosttalent"}))`.  Also, because careers is misspelled, the formula returns 3.5 instead of 3.25.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore AVERAGEIFS and do it the old fashioned way, from before AVERAGEIFS existed:

```
=AVERAGE(IF((A2:A11="hostcareers")+(A2:A11="hosttalent"), B2:B11))
```

You generate two arrays based on the conditions and add them:

```
(A2:A11="hostcareers")+(A2:A11="hosttalent")
```

The two results sets will be an array of TRUE/FALSE values where the source range matches the condition.  Adding them is the equivalent of using OR*.  Pass that to IF with the data range, and you'll get an array containing all the corresponding numbers from the data range or FALSE if neither conditions was met.

```
IF((A2:A11="hostcareers")+(A2:A11="hosttalent"), B2:B11)
```

Pass that to AVERAGE and you've got it.

* if you wanted to simulate AND, you'd multiply them.

Comment: that worked as well; the how I wanted to approach it; but thanks for the explanation.

Comment: What if there's another range and criteria? How would you go about that?

Comment: You just keep appending them, for instance: `(A2:A11="hostcareers")+(A2:A11="hosttalent")+(B2:B11="test")`.   Use + for an OR logic.  As noted before, AND is like multiplying.  You can mix AND and OR logics, but you'd have to bracket it, just like you would any complicated boolean.

Comment: =AVERAGE(IF((SurveyResultsForSept!B2:B1600="hostnamecareers")+(SurveyResultsForSept!B2:B1600="hostnametalent")+(SurveyResultsForSept!D2:D1600, "On-Demand Video"), SurveyResultsForSept!D2:D1600))) that's not working for me.

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: I think I figured it out, I forgot to add the "=" sign for the third criteria.

Comment: right, it's a little confusing at first because with the built-in IFS formulas you comma separate the range and the criteria, but when you're doing the array combination you don't.

Comment: Yes it is, but I am happy to have to figured it out. I am still learning more about writing functions(s) in Excel. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: no problem, let me know if you have any other issues with this.  If this helped you, consider accepting it as the answer.